# Accessing invoice data with a subscription in Recurly PHP API

Tags: php, recurly

I am working with the Recurly PHP API and am trying to figure out a way to find out if a subscription has overdue invoices hence the subscription is overdue (even when there are overdue invoices the subscription state does not change and still shows as active).

To access the subscription I am using:

```
try{
    $subscriptions = Recurly_SubscriptionList::getForAccount('1');
    foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) { 
        print $subscription;
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
activated_at="2014-10-08 13:18:27 +00:00", 
collection_method="manual", 
currency="USD", 
current_period_ends_at="2014-11-08 14:00:00 +00:00", 
current_period_started_at="2014-10-08 14:00:00 +00:00", 
invoice=, 
net_terms=0, 
plan="", 
quantity=120, 
state="active", 
subscription_add_ons=[], 
trial_ends_at="2014-10-08 14:00:00 +00:00", 
trial_started_at="2014-10-08 13:18:27 +00:00", 
unit_amount_in_cents=500, 
uuid="VALUE"
```

Within $subscription is invoice but it is blank, however, if I use:

```
print_r($subscription->invoice);
```

it returns:

```
Recurly_Stub Object ( [objectType] => invoice [_href:protected] => https://subdomain.recurly.com/v2/invoices/1004 [_client:protected] => [_links:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Invoice 1004 is an overdue invoice so I want to be able to show that the subscription is overdue but I cannot access the _href:protected value and cannot see any other way of determining if a subscription contains overdue invoices?

Does anyone know an alternate way to tell if a subscription contains overdue invoices or, failing that, how can I access _href:protected so I can at least then run the get invoice API against the invoice to check?

Comment: Dear bhttoan, kindly update if you have worked it out. I'm also trying the same.

Comment: @sariDon give my answer a look. guessing you've figured it out by now though.

Answer (score 4):

The short version is you should call `$subscription->invoice->get()`. `$subscription->invoice` returns a `Recurly_Stub` object and you'd need to call its `get()` method to force it to load the full object.

We [document this](https://docs.recurly.com/client-libraries/php#fetching_linked_resources) but clearly we don't have it in the right spot.

Stepping back though, you might find it's faster to just get all the past due invoices `Recurly_InvoiceList::getPastDue()` and look for their subscriptions.